# How do i add simple products to configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product

How do i add simple products under configurable products? I've created the simple products separately and before the configurable products, so they are standalone products.

Comment: May sound like a dumb question, but do you want via code, or how to do it in admin?

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming you already completed the basic steps:

1. Create attributes by which the product should be configurable (e.g. color, size, ...). The attributes need to have scope "global", be of input type "dropdown" and be enabled to be used with configurable products.
2. Add the attribute to the desired attributes.
3. Create the simple products and select the values for the configurable attribute (color, size, ...). If you don't want the simple products to be found individually you can set the "Visibility" to "Not Visible Individually".

Now you can continue and create a configurable product.

1. Create a new configurable product using the desired attribute set:

   [image: Select attribute set and type]
2. Select the attributes by which the product will be configurable:

   [image: Select configurable attributes]
3. Switch to the tab "Associated Products" and search for the simple products representing the options for you configurable product:

   [image: Add simple products]
4. Fill in the other required attributes (name, SKU, price, availability, ...) and save. The configurable product will show up in the frontend.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't getting the trick with the attributes and I was wondering why my subproducts are not appearing when i search them in the Associated products page. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm happy I could help you. Please can you accept my answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that others know that this works?

Comment: thank you, your answer just helped me connect a bunch of products i created via the QUICK CREATE and didn't save. the products saved but the association didn't, i was just about to delete and recreate them because i wasn't sure how to connect them.

Comment: But isn't this creating a child product by super attribute? what about in the regular way not the super attribute way? Also, my regular product doesn't show up under that search.